# Thread is stuck when executing SerialPort.Close()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, serial-port

I am facing a problem that a thread in my application runs into a deadlock when I want to close the serial port of a gsm terminal. This problem is well known [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-_5b00_kim-hamilton_5d00_.aspx) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce8ce1a3-64ed-4f26-b9ad-e2ff1d3be0a5/serial-port-hangs-whilst-closing?forum=Vsexpressvcs) but all advices in these threads didn't help me.

```
/// <summary>
///     Closes the COM port, prevents reading and writing
/// </summary>
public void Stop()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("stop called");
    var block = true;
    var bgw = new BackgroundWorker
    {
        WorkerReportsProgress = false,
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = false,
    };

    bgw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (!CanAccessPort())
            return;

        try
        {
            _serialPort.DataReceived -= Read;
            GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(_serialPort.BaseStream);
            _serialPort.Close();
            _isOpen = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(PORTERROR, ex);
        }
    };

    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("block is set to false =)");
        block = false;
    };

    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    while (block)
        Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

The code above runs forever when `_serialPort.Close()` is executed. As a recommended advice I read about running the close operation in a separate thread. I tried with `BackgroundWorker` and `Thread` classes but nothing did work. Using `AutoResetEvent` as suggested in another thread did not work either. Before closing the port I am sending some commands to it and receive several results but it won't close. When I run a simple command line program that starts the port, reads data and tries to close it, everything works and even without threads.

What could cause the deadlock? I am not doing any GUI related stuff as mentioned in almost all other answers.

DataReceived event handler code here:

```
/// <summary>
///     Reads input from the COM interface and invokes the corresponding event depending on the input
/// </summary>
private void Read(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var buffer = new char[1024];
    var counter = 0;
    _keepRunning = true;
     if (_timeout == null)
     {
        // timeout must be at least 3 seconds because when sending a sms to the terminal the receive notification (+CSDI) can be lost with less timeout 
        _timeout = new Timer(3000);
        _timeout.Elapsed += (s, ev) =>
        {
            _keepRunning = false;
            _timeout.Stop();
        };
    }
    _timeout.Start();

    // cancel condition: no more new data for 3 seconds or "OK"/"ERROR" found within the result
    while (_keepRunning)
    {
        var toRead = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        if (toRead == 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            continue;
        }
        _timeout.Stop();
        _timeout.Start();

        counter += _serialPort.Read(buffer, counter, toRead);

        // ok or error found in result string
        var tmp = new string(buffer).Replace("\0", "").Trim();
        if (tmp.EndsWith("OK") || tmp.EndsWith("ERROR"))
        {
            _timeout.Stop();
            _keepRunning = false;
        }
    }

    // remove empty array slots from the back
    var nullTerminalCounter = 0;
    for (var i = buffer.Length - 1; i != 0; i--)
    {
        if (buffer[i] == '\0')
        {
            nullTerminalCounter++;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    Array.Resize(ref buffer, buffer.Length - nullTerminalCounter);
    var str = new String(buffer).Trim();

    // result must be something different than incoming messages (+CMTI: \"MT\", 25)
    if (!((str.StartsWith("+CMTI") || str.StartsWith("+CSDI")) && str.Length < 20))
    {
        // when an incoming message is received, it does not belong to the command issued, so result has not yet arrived, hence port is still blocked!
        _isBlocked = false;
        Debug.WriteLine("port is unblocked");
    }


    var args = new CommandReturnValueReceivedEventArgs
    {
        ResultString = str
    };
    OnCommandReturnValueReceived(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that didn't solve anything.  You in fact made it twice as bad, not only will 'Close() deadlock, the BackgroundWorker does as well.  Caused by `while (block)`.  You are doing something very unsanitary in one of the SerialPort event handlers, we can't see it.

Comment: Why is `Close()` deadlocking? That is my question =). And `block` is set to `false` when the background worker has finished so if `Close()` does not deadlock, everything is fine.

Comment: You are right...I was using this code for 2 months and except for the problem with closing everything worked but I didn't notice the problem with the timeout here until now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if (toRead == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        continue;
    }
```

This code is the basic source of the deadlock.  The rule for SerialPort.Close() is that it can only close the serial port when none of the event handlers for SerialPort are active.  Problem is, your DataReceived event handler is almost *always* active, waiting for data.  This was not the intended use for the event.  You are supposed to read whatever is available from the serial port, typically appending bytes to a buffer and *get out*.  The event fires again when more bytes are available.

```
   while (_keepRunning)
```

Looks like you discovered this problem and tried to fix it with the Timer.  That doesn't work either, in a *very* ratty way that's very difficult to debug.  A *bool* variable is not a proper synchronization primitive, like ManualResetEvent.  The while() loop will not see the _keepRunning variable turn to *false* when you target x86 and run the Release build of your program.  Which enables the jitter optimizer, it is apt to store the variable in a cpu register.  Declaring the variable *volatile* is required to suppress that optimization.

I *suspect*, but can't guarantee, that using *volatile* will solve your problem.  And you probably want to set _keepRunning to *false* before calling Close() so you don't get the timeout delay.

A more structural fix is however indicated.  Rewrite the DataReceived event handler so it never loops waiting for data.  Given that this appears to be code to talk to a modem, a simple `_serialPort.ReadLine()` call should be all that's required.

Comment: Oh look!  Waiting in a GUI event-handler again.

Answer (score 0):

The issues I had went away if I ensured that `Open` and `Close` never were called at the same time by any thread. I did this by using a lock.

The essence is the following.

```
lock(_port)
    _port.Open(.....);

...

lock(_port)
    _port.Close(.....);
```